# how to get ng-included url value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a main file which includes a file inside a subfolder using `ng-include`, like this,

```
<p ng-include=" 'activity/act01/' "></p>
```

where the `ng-include` value will change dynamically

then, how can i get current value of `ng-include`.

Comment: bind it to a controller property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-include` binds to an expression.  This is why your example requires single quotes.  It wants an expression returning a string.  This can be function returning a string, a variable, or a literal string.  Because of this, it is easy to bind `ng-include` to a scope variable.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.actPage = 'activity/act01/';

  $scope.goToActTwo = function(){
    $scope.actPage = 'activity/act02';
  };
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div ng-include="actPage"></div>

  <button ng-click="goToActTwo()">Change Act</button>
</div>
```